# Looking for good IoT reading material

Tags: discussion

Is there any regular publication (or even a book(s)) on IoT in general? Or good online sites, worthy of regular reading?

I would be interested in articles on:

- SBCs, such as ESP and Raspberry Pi (Zero W)
- Sensors
- Protocols, such as BT, BLE, ZigeBee, LoRa(Wan)
- Concepts like mesh networking, DTN
- Reporting mechanisms, such as MQTT
- Dashboards & reporting tools, such as NodeRed, ThingsBoard, etc
- Other FFPOSS server-side software
- Projects, such as wearables, trackers, etc
- Code snippets
- Etc, etc, etc

Btw, if this belongs in chat, rather than here, or even community wiki, please move it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is difficult for two reasons. First the subject is very wide, spanning the home automation (really, why has nobody made this work yet?) playground to [industrial](https://www.mbed.com/built-with-mbed/) applications. As you have identified, it also spans the whole stack and more (actually, many applications are close to needing custom silicon to be cost effective).

Secondly, unless companies are selling infrastructure, they are unlikely to be keen to teach you how to compete with them, or how to use a competitor's product. Of course, once you're working inside a 'developer' company, much of this stuff becomes much more trivial to pick up because you're working with at least a half-stable stack and just making tweaks. If you're doing this for a hobby, you're probably stuck at the 'hackaday' level, and limited by available time to cover everything.

Looking (for example) through the mbed blog, there are a few good technical posts. These might be useful to you, but only start to cover a subject - and I'm not sure they count as regular reading.